# ThreeJS: Thickness of the BufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

Is there any possibility to add the thickness to the  buffer geometry? Here, I have a buffer geometry with vertices, indices for the geometry details. Here, I want to update the thickness of the buffer geometry. I can able  to increase/decrease the size of the height, width or depth of the geometry, but I have no idea how can I increase/decrease the thickness of the geometry.
Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hw0c9x3L/

```
// Three.js - Custom Geometry - Cube - Vertex Colors
// from https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-custom-geometry-cube-vertex-colors.html

import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 5;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1,  1),  // 0
    new THREE.Vector3( 1, -1,  1),  // 1
    new THREE.Vector3(-1,  1,  1),  // 2
    new THREE.Vector3( 1,  1,  1),  // 3
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, -1),  // 4
    new THREE.Vector3( 1, -1, -1),  // 5
    new THREE.Vector3(-1,  1, -1),  // 6
    new THREE.Vector3( 1,  1, -1),  // 7
  );

  /*
       6----7
      /|   /|
     2----3 |
     | |  | |
     | 4--|-5
     |/   |/
     0----1
  */

  geometry.faces.push(
     // front
     new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2),
     new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 3),

  );

  geometry.faces.forEach((face, ndx) => {
    face.vertexColors = [
      (new THREE.Color()).setHSL(ndx / 12      , 1, 0.5),
      (new THREE.Color()).setHSL(ndx / 12 + 0.1, 1, 0.5),
      (new THREE.Color()).setHSL(ndx / 12 + 0.2, 1, 0.5),
    ];
  });

  geometry.computeFaceNormals();

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;
    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x44FF44,  0),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x4444FF, -4),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0xFF4444,  4),
  ];

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = 1 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

Comment: What do you mean thickness? With a cube, changing its scale changes its thickness in each direction.

Comment: @Marquizzo I mean the thickness of the plane. In the sample, I will be having a face of the cube and I'm looking for the thickness of the face (plane)

Comment: You can't change the thickness of a plane. It's infinitely thin. Although you could fake thickness by making two planes parallel to each other.